# Cite author in paper text in tfnlm bibliography style

Tags: citing, natbib

Below is the current code, where I have to write the author name by myself manually and add the `$\emph{et al.}$` after it. The `\cite{SmithTest}` is used to produce the reference in the end.

```
\documentclass[]{interact}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Smith $\emph{et al.}$ proposed about blahblah \cite{SmithTest}.

\bibliographystyle{tfnlm}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Here is the bib file `test.bib`:

```
@article{SmithTest,
  title = {Test item},
  author = {Smith, A and Smith, B and Smith, C and Smith, D},
  year = {2022},
  journal = {Test},
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

But is there any way that I can use the bib key and generate the `Smith et al.` automatically such as:

```
\how_to_cite{SmithTest} proposed about blahblah \cite{SmithTest}.
```

I tried searching here using `cite author`, etc, but could not solve it.

I don't know how to correctly express my problem and title with the right word. So, please tell me about it if there is any unclarity. Or if there are already some answers here.

**Update**

The `tfnlm` is the Taylor & Francis Interactive style, which can be obtained from the [official website](http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/InteractNLMLaTeX.zip) or [overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-nlm-reference-style/bngwgqnxcxrp).

Comment: Is the `tfnlm` bib style available online? Is the `tfnlm` bibliography style able to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs? One way to find out would be to (a) change `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[authoryear, round]{natbib}`, (b) omit the `\bibpunct` directive, and (c) rerun BibTeX and LaTeX twice more on your document.

Comment: @Mico The style is part of the Taylor & Francis Intercative style. It's on Overleaf: https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-nlm-reference-style/bngwgqnxcxrp

Comment: @Mico, did as you said, but got `Package natbib: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.
`. And @ManuelWeinkauf is right that `tfnlm` is the Taylor & Francis Intercative style, which can also be download from [http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/InteractNLMLaTeX.zip](http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/InteractNLMLaTeX.zip)

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but you don't have to (and really should not!) switch to maths mode just to write in italics. `$\emph{et al.}$` can just be `\emph{et al.}`. Maths mode should never be used to force italic output, it should be used for mathematics.

Comment: @moewe, thanks. I have changed all to `\emph{et al.}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the template on Overleaf, I do not think Taylor & Francis considered this possibility or prepared any implementation for it.

`\citeauthor{}`, as suggested by user187803, does not work with the `tfnlm`-bibstyle. The style supports `\authorcite{}`, but this cites the key, not the author name. So `\authorcite{SmithTest} proposed about blahblah` results in "SmithTest proposed about blahblah", not any form of "Smith et al. proposed about blahblah".

On the one hand, the publisher may discourage or even forbid "author [number]" style citations altogether. In this case, it may be advisable to reframe the text in a passive way like `It was shown that blahblah \cite{SmithTest}`.

If you want to use it regardless, I would assume the easiest way to get a consistent layout would be to define your own command for it:

```
\newcommand{\CiteOneAuth}[2]{#1 \cite{#2}}
\newcommand{\CiteMultAuth}[2]{#1 \textit{et al.} \cite{#2}}

\CiteMultAuth{Smith}{SmithTest} proposed about blahblah
```

The disadvantage will be that you will have to pay attention yourself that

1. You use the correct version for articles with one vs. several authors
2. You make sure to manually use the correct name in each case

Comment: Thanks for your help, the `tfnlm` indeed is the Taylor & Francis Interactive style. After checking their previous publication, your point about discouragement of "author [number]" style seems to be right. I also tried your command, but it did not work.

Comment: @yangtzech It probably did not work because I forgot the backslash before `\cite{}`. Corrected now and this should work now.

Comment: Thanks, but there should also be a backslash before  `CiteOneAuth` and `CiteMultAuth`. Is it possible to put the `[number]` at the end of sentence, instead of right behind the `author`?

Comment: @yangtzech Yes, correct, I forgot those backslashes as well. For the second question: technically yes but not without introducing lots of unforeseeable problems. You could have a command `\newcommand{\CiteMultAuth}[3]{#1 \textit{et al.} #3 \cite{#2}}`, which you could use like `\CiteMultAuth{Smith}{SmithTest}{proposed about blahblah}, but this is not advisable, as the third argument would be very long (which makes the braces unwieldy) and could be prone to problems with any special formatting.

Comment: @yangtzech It is also not at good idea to separate the author name and number, like in "Smith et al. proposed about blahblah [1]", as it physically separates what belongs together. You would not write "Smith et al. proposed about blahblah (2022)", but instead "Smith et al. (2022) proposed about blahblah" In the same way, the typographically correct version to use numeric citation with author names in-text is "Smith et al. [1] proposed about blahblah", **not** "Smith et al. proposed about blahblah [1]". This would only work with the passive form "It was proposed that blahblah [1]".

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

Often you can use `\citeauthor`, but it might not work with your `tfnlm` style. Here is an example with `abbrvnat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{SmithTest,
  title = {Test item},
  author = {Smith, A and Smith, B and Smith, C and Smith, D},
  year = {2022},
  journal = {Test},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Smith $\emph{et al.}$ proposed about blahblah \cite{SmithTest}.

\citeauthor{SmithTest} proposed about blahblah \cite{SmithTest}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried `\citeauthor{SmithTest}`, and you are right that it did not work. It will result in `(author?)`